# Remove row from db with EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, delete-row

I try to use the following function to remove a item:

```
        internal static bool Remove(T record)
        {

            int result = 0;

            // get db set
            DatabaseDbContext context = new DatabaseDbContext();
            DbSet<T> set = context.Set<T>();

            // remove item
            set.Remove(record);

            // clean up
            context.Dispose();
            record.Dispose();

            // return result 
            return result > 0;
        }
```

I get the error: "The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager."

How can I modify this to work like I want?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Attach to attach an existing record to the current context. This lets you avoid retrieving the record from the database in order to delete it.

```
context.Set<T>().Attach(item);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ObjectContext.Attach Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.attach.aspx).

> Call Attach on the ObjectContext to attach the object to the object context. Do this when the object already exists in the data source but is currently not attached to the context

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, but there has to be a better way?

```
        internal static bool Remove(T record)
        {

            int result = 0;

            // remove item
            DatabaseDbContext context = new DatabaseDbContext();
            T item = context.Set<T>().Where(r => r.Id == record.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            context.Set<T>().Remove(item);
            result = context.SaveChanges();

            // clean up
            context.Dispose();
            record.Dispose();

            // return result 
            return result > 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 context.Entry(record).State = EntityState.Deleted;
 context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to delete Range of entities using InsertedDate

```
 public bool Delete_Programs_By_Date(DateTime programDate)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var db = new Context())
                {
                   db.Program.RemoveRange(db.Program.Where(x => x.InsertedDate == programDate).ToList());
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```